# Wanderlust -- Open e-mail in new buffer, instead of split-window

Tags: emacs

Any ideas regarding how to configure Wanderlust to open emails in a new buffer, instead of a split window?  There is just too much happening with four (4) windows -- summary message buffer; message buffer; big brother insidious database address manager; and the mini-buffer.  (See the screenshot below.)

I think I've located the relevant portion of the code in `wl-message.el`, but I'm not sure what portion to change.  `(setq wl-message-window-size '(1 . 1))` in the `init.el` is **not** what I'm looking for, because I'd still have to share the screen with other buffers.

I'm spending a lot of time switching and closing windows to get a full size buffer, and I'm hoping to just eliminate multiple windows when checking my e-mail.

Thanks . . . any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
;;; wl-message.el -- Message buffer handling from summary buffer.

(defun wl-message-buffer-window ()
  "Get message buffer window if any."
  (let* ((start-win (selected-window))
     (cur-win start-win))
    (catch 'found
      (while (progn
           (setq cur-win (next-window cur-win))
           (with-current-buffer (window-buffer cur-win)
         (if (or (eq major-mode 'wl-message-mode)
             (eq major-mode 'mime-view-mode))
             (throw 'found cur-win)))
           (not (eq cur-win start-win)))))))

(defun wl-message-select-buffer (buffer)
  "Select BUFFER as a message buffer."
  (let ((window (get-buffer-window buffer))
    (sum (car wl-message-window-size))
    (mes (cdr wl-message-window-size))
    whi)
    (when (and window
           (not (eq (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
              wl-message-buffer-cur-summary-buffer)
            (current-buffer))))
      (delete-window window)
      (run-hooks 'wl-message-window-deleted-hook)
      (setq window nil))
    (if window
    (select-window window)
      (when wl-fixed-window-configuration
    (delete-other-windows)
    (and wl-stay-folder-window
         (wl-summary-toggle-disp-folder)))
      ;; There's no buffer window. Search for message window and snatch it.
      (if (setq window (wl-message-buffer-window))
      (select-window window)
    (setq whi (1- (window-height)))
    (if mes
        (progn
          (let ((total (+ sum mes)))
        (setq sum (max window-min-height (/ (* whi sum) total)))
        (setq mes (max window-min-height (/ (* whi mes) total))))
          (if (< whi (+ sum mes))
          (enlarge-window (- (+ sum mes) whi)))))
    (split-window (get-buffer-window (current-buffer)) sum)
    (other-window 1)))
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)))
```

[image: multiple_windows]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/multiple_windows.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION # 1:   The variable `wl-message-buffer-name` that is defined within `wl-vars.el` makes the message buffer uninteresting by virtue of the space at the beginning of the buffer name:      `*WL:Message*`.  Inasmuch as Emacs hides uninteresting buffers by default, one solution is to modify the aforementioned variable by removing the space at the beginning of the buffer name.  That way, the buffer is always visible and it is just a matter of switching to the window that displays the message and then `delete-other-windows`.  The added advantage is that it is no longer necessary to return to the summary buffer to view an e-mail that has already been opened, since there is already an open buffer dedicated to said e-mail.

```
(defcustom wl-message-buffer-name "*WL:Message*" ;; " *WL:Message*"
  "*Buffer name for message buffers."
  :group 'wl-pref
  :group 'wl-setting)
```

---

SOLUTION # 2:  This second solution is no longer the preferred method and will most likely be removed entirely from this answer.  The word search utility I was using could not comb the `wl-vars.el` file for some unknown reason, so this second solution was a workaround.

Edit the key map for `wl-summary-read` (inside `wl-summary.el`) and replace it with the function `lawlist-wl-summary-read` so that hitting the space bar activates said function.  `wl-summary-enter-handler` remains defined as the enter key, which opens messages in the default manner.

```
(define-key wl-summary-mode-map " "    'lawlist-wl-summary-read)

(defun lawlist-wl-summary-read nil
  "Clone the the buffer and make new buffer name unique."
(interactive)
    (wl-summary-enter-handler)
    (windmove-down)
    (let ((n 0)
        bufname)
    (while (progn
             (setq bufname (concat "email"
                                   (if (= n 0) "" (int-to-string n))
                                   "")) ;; could be an ending, like an asterick *
             (setq n (1- n)) ;; if + instead of -, then no hyphen and no space between buffer name and the number
             (get-buffer bufname)))
    (clone-indirect-buffer bufname nil)
    (switch-to-buffer bufname)
    (delete-other-windows) ))
```